# Scroll element to the top of the container onclick

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, scrolltop

I've a section that contains severals elements.

**I need to scroll up the number 5 , like the 1rst div.** similar way like the tipical scrolling page.

I need to **animate** it as well. And **scroll it up to the higher**. like the 1rst. I don't care if the upper div's are hidden

```
 <section>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</section>
<button> Click and show Div 5 up</button>
```

JS

```
$("button").click(function() {

  $('div:eq(5)').animate({scrollTop: $('div:ep(0)'}, 3000);
});
```

I leave you the code-->

http://codepen.io/blackersoul/pen/KwLkj

Comment: have you considered '<a href="#div1"></a>'?

Comment: eddited 4 better understand @tborychowski

Answer (score 0):

Javascript arrays are zero-based.
So the 5th element in this case is actually 4. (0 - 1 - 2 - 3 - 4)

Try this:

```
$("button").click(function() {
  var offset = $("div:eq(4)").offset().top;
  $('section').scrollTop(offset, 2000);
});
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yadgm)

Comment: Great, but I need to animate it as well.
And scroll it up to the higher. like the 1rst. I don't care if the upper div's are hidden

Comment: So you want the actual fifth element to scroll to the position of the first element?

Comment: Yes ! I'd like ! @FabianMeul